# How to test the uplink/upload link speed

Tags: android, networking

I'm really struggling on how to test an uplink to the internet. I know how to do download link speed but upload is really a problem.

Do I have to implement my own server on the internet?

Is there a way to use an http post? a connection-less protocol?

I looked into using an ftp free server but I didn't find one that allows to remove the file I uploaded.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The speed, actually throughput, you measure on the Internet is only good between the two end-points of the test. Testing to/from a different remote end-point can yield very different results due to the traffic taking a different path across the different ISPs that make up the Internet. This is because some paths are longer than others, different ISPs have different network designs, and some ISPs are more congested than other ISPs. Even between the same end-points, the throughput can vary by the time of day. The most accurate measure is between you and your ISP's first-hop router.

Comment: Don't disagree. But the question is how? I don't believe that Ping is suitable for bandwidth if ever ping is allowed? I think the only way of measuring is to upload data to a server via http, ftp or a socket?